# Unable to upload apk on google although using the same key?

Tags: android

I want to upload an updated apk on playstore but I am getting error that my SHA1 certificates are not matching with the previous one. I want to know how I can upload the apk as I am using the same old key that was previously used by the developer.

Comment: Is there conflict because I have shifted the project from eclipse to studio or SHA1 certificates are different as PC's used  are different first time and now with different sHA keys.

Comment: The SHA1 will be different for different computers. U need same Credentials to publish an update to app. The credentials is a Keystore file.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously not using the same certificate, hence the message.

The debug certificates are different among computers but from your message I suspect the app is already uploaded to the store, so you need to use the same release certificate used by the other developer. Ask the other developer which certificate he used.

Comment: I dont have a sound about the certificates, the previous developer only provides me the key and password. I thought that the key that he used in past to sign the apk will be suffice. What else do I need to solve my issue?

Comment: You need to ask him the same keystore he used.